# Dependency problem with tor

Tags: 12.04, tor

I am trying to install tor via [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) tutorial via option 2.
I receive this error when finally installing tor via `sudo apt-get install tor`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  tor : Depends:
libseccomp2 (>= 0.0.0~20120605) but it is not installable E: Unable to
correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the Tor Bundle on the Tor Project site. Extract the archive in any directory, the enter it by terminal and type ./start-tor-browser